# Convert JSON array containing pairs to a list of points

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "points": [88,223,88,223,91,223]
}
```

and I need to map it to my following class using `Jackson`:

```
public MyClass {
    public List<Point2D.Float> points;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: From which package `Point2D` comes from? What these numbers represents? Do you want to map each number to a new `Point2D.Float` or each two numbers creates new `Point2D.Float`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jackson-integrated way of doing this is to implement and register a custom `JsonDeserializer` for the list of `Point2D.Float` elements.

For example, implement a `JsonDeserializer` to parse the `"points"` JSON array as a `float[]`, then take pairs from the array and create `Point2D.Float` objects from them. Add those to a `List<Point2D.Float>` and return it.

That might look like

```
class PointsDeser extends JsonDeserializer<List<Point2D.Float>> {
    @Override
    public List<Point2D.Float> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        float[] coords = ctxt.readValue(p, float[].class);
        if (coords.length % 2 != 0) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Expected an even number of values.");
        }
        List<Point2D.Float> points = new ArrayList<>(coords.length / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i += 2) {
            points.add(new Point2D.Float(coords[i], coords[i + 1]));
        }
        return points;
    }
}
```

Then annotate your property with `@JsonDeserialize` pointing to the right deserializer class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = PointsDeser.class)
public void setPoints(List<Point2D.Float> points) {
    this.points = points;
}
```

and use Jackson as you normally would

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass instance = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

---

If you can't annotate your `MyClass` directly, use a [mixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Answer (score 1):

First, parse the JSON using JSON parser of your choice (Jackson apparently).

Second, iterate the list/array, 2 values at a time, e.g.

```
public static List<Point2D.Float> toPoints(List<Float> coords) {
    List<Point2D.Float> points = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator<Float> iter = coords.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(iter.next(), iter.next()));
    return points;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(toPoints(List.of(88f, 223f, 88f, 223f, 91f, 223f)));
```

*Output*

```
[Point2D.Float[88.0, 223.0], Point2D.Float[88.0, 223.0], Point2D.Float[91.0, 223.0]]
```